# Multiple float/block/div within anchor tag

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I need to achieve something like this:

```
<a style="display:block;" href="#">
  <div style="float:left;display:block;">Left</div>
  <div>
    <div style="display:block;">Right</div>
    <div style="display:block;">Right Bottom</div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Basically a button with 2 columns and the right column having 2 rows.

It shows up correctly in modern browsers with inline/block support but in IE6 and IE7, whenever I hover the left div (with float) it'll display as the 'select' text icon instead of the hand icon (i believe once float, block will be cancelled and displayed as inline). Is there any way I can achieve this without using an image as a whole? I need it to be text because it's important for SEO and retina displays.

:( :(

Comment: IE6, IE7 and retina displays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank" style="display:block; overflow: hidden" href="#">
  <div style="float:left; width:150px;">Left</div>

  <div style="float:right; width:150px;">
    <div style="display:block;">Right</div>
    <div style="display:block;">Right Bottom</div>
  </div>

  <div style="clear: both;"></div><!-- This will clear the floats for IE -->
</a>
```

To avoid text cursor add this CSS -

```
a div{cursor: pointer;}
```

**Demo** - http://jsfiddle.net/ZhKmr/4/

Comment: Hmm still no luck with IE6 and 7. Still showing the 'select text' icon instead of a hand.

Comment: @EdwinNg Check the code now you needed a div{cursor: pointer;}

Comment: Still showing the select text icon in Ie6/7. I think my problem is whenever a float is written, it'll display as inline regardless if you've written a block. Guess this is more like a inline-block problem. Is there any other way I can achieve that layout? 2 columns with 2 rows on right column, in text form and link.